# Install Toshiba e-studio 455 on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, printing, toshiba

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

I want to install network printer Toshiba e-Studio 455, but in Driver database there are only entries for 450, 450s, 451c, 452 and 453.
When I used driver for 450 and tried to print test page, printer printed page with following context:

```
ERROR:
invalidfont
OFFENDING COMMAND:
$definefont
STACK:
--nostringval--
/TVZYWM+Ubuntu-Medium
--nostringval--
/TVZYWM+Ubuntu-Medium
--nostringval--
--nostringval--
14
```

How can I install this printer to work properly or from where can I download a correct driver?

Comment: Here is the link to download the drivers for your printer http://business.toshiba.com/support/downloads.jsp?SELCTD_MODEL=e-STUDIO455&AXN=SELCTD

Comment: OK, I followed link. How to install these drivers? I there some linux binary...

Comment: Herman I would suggest you to first visit this link http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting and  check compatibility with current linux versions

Comment: On OpenPrinting page there isn't e-studio 455 on their supported printers list...

Comment: Herman in looking for a solution to the issue you are facing. I got to know that this a bug which is already reported and people are trying to diagnose it.Here is the link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/978120

Comment: @VRU Thank you for info. I am maybe stupid, but status *Fix Released* doesn't mean, that they release the fix and bug should not occur now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround is:

```
lpadmin -p TOSHIBA-ColorMFP  -o pdftops-renderer-default=pdftops
```

if, your printer is indeed called TOSHIBA-ColorMFP. Check the name of your printers with:

```
lpstat -a
```

Comment: I have no idea what it is doing, but it's working

Comment: It is forcing a render to postscript through GNU Postscript and sends that to the printer. This will fix many things, since GNU postscript is much more forgiving when parsing PDF than some printers are. If I understand things correctly... @MichałHerman

Comment: Via the GUI you can also go to Printers (search for it in Unity) -> right click the printer -> Printer Properties -> Job Options ->  Other Options (Advanced) (at the very bottom of the page) -> Add a new option -> "pdftops-renderer", then set its value to pdftops and apply.

Answer (score 0):

Another workround is to use the "Generic PCL" driver as the eStudio printers don't like being sent font data by postscript - the PCL6XL drivers will even do colour.